# Django CMS : How to place a button inside CMS preserving the link

Tags: html, django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am using text plugin ( ck-editor ):

Below is my source:

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'" type="button">www.example.com</button>
```

After saving the text plugin, I could notice that the source under text plugin has changed as below:

```
 <button type="button">www.example.com</button>
```

Am I using a wrong plugin? How to handle this case by preserving the link of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ckeditor sanitises content but you can specify additional tags & attributes as you can see [here](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor#configurable-sanitizer) which shows you can provide these settings;

```
TEXT_ADDITIONAL_TAGS = ('iframe',)
TEXT_ADDITIONAL_ATTRIBUTES = ('scrolling', 'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder')
```

So you could add set `TEXT_ADDITIONAL_ATTRIBUTES = ('onclick', )`

Comment: Thanks, I have totally turned the sanitation of ckeditor off. TEXT_HTML_SANITIZE = False

Comment: @nkkrishnak Just be careful with things like that. As soon as you do that kind of thing you open up the chance of malicious actions like scripts being added that aren't safe etc